# How to adjust re.compile to accept multiple variations/options?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-re

Currently working on this code that will scan my email and return all occurrences with the pattern below. For example, it would return ABC123456 Line 10 Seq 1 1/1/2022. Is there anyway I could make the Line and Seq parts optional? For example, my scan would still pick-up **ABC123456 1/1/2022** or **ABC123456 Line 10 1/1/2022**?

```
pattern = re.compile(r"([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+) Line ([0-9]+) Seq ([0-9]) ([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+)")
matches = pattern.finditer(body)
writer.writerows(map(lambda m: m.groups(), matches))
break
```

Comment: Use `|` in the regexp to specify alternative patterns.

Comment: You can also specify optional parts of a pattern with `(pattern)?`

Comment: @Barmar sorry, could you clarify please? I'm very new to coding

Answer (score 0):

You may use the regex `a|b` token which matches either the expressions `a` or `b`. So your regex could be:

```
r"([a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)( Line ([0-9]+ )| )(Seq ([0-9]) |)([0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/[0-9]+)"
```

Comment: yeah thats super close to what I want. Thanks so much :) only thing is that it exports 6 columns instead of 4. Instead of just 10 and 1, it'll export Line 10 10 Seq 1 1. would like to make sure that "Line 10" and "Seq 1" don't show up in the csv. Any tips?